# How can I do successive joins in a for loop without reassigning variable?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am doing successive joins between two dataframes with `pyspark`.

I am doing this in a for-loop:

```py
for variable in variables:
    df1 = df1.join(df2,variable,'left_outer')
```

**This results in `df1` being reassigned multiple times. Is this an issue ?**

How can I chain operations while not writing

```py
df1.join(df2,variables[0])
.join(df2,variables[1])
.join(df2,variables[2])
...
```

**EDIT**

Using `functools.reduce()` is not an option as it would lead to worse performance as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977549/using-pythons-reduce-to-join-multiple-pyspark-dataframes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge several dataframes column-wise in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080087/how-to-merge-several-dataframes-column-wise-in-pyspark)

Comment: @user10465355: The answer to the duplicated question leads to worse performance as detailed here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977549/using-pythons-reduce-to-join-multiple-pyspark-dataframes

Comment: Thank you very much for the links and explanation (your code runs twice the same function g (dfs) if I'm not mistaken but f and g are both just as fast)

Comment: My mistake. I've pasted wrong part. But the timings are pretty much the same (within reasonable limits).